# Flutter Firebase Twitter Auth throwing error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to incorporate Twitter auth inside of my Flutter app. I'm following the FlutterFire documentation but I get an error thrown. I was wondering if there is an issue on my end or with the twitter login plugin. Here is my code:

```
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithTwitter() async {
    // Create a TwitterLogin instance
    final twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
        apiKey: '<1qOvE68aiVbk4URSARlfm0758>',
        apiSecretKey: ' <wQHWRYBweiV5DvEecSUTeSbnT6uwB6080D4vz6WDyY1geT8Paz>',
        redirectURI: '<twitter-firebase-auth>://');

    // Trigger the sign-in flow
    final authResult = twitterLogin.login();

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: authResult.authToken!,
      secret: authResult.authTokenSecret!,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
The getter 'authToken' isn't defined for the type 'Future<AuthResult>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'authToken', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'authToken'.
```

Comment: It looks like AuthResult doesn't have a authToken property.  Looks like that tutorial might be out of date.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult

Answer (score 1):

You should do it.

```
final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).